# How to log client side errors to a centralised file or dashboard (in React)

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, client, error-logging

I want log all the client side errors in a centralised logging file .Can anyone tell me how to do this in react.(Client side error logging).I am not able to find support for this in react.Can anyone tell how to implement it by a small demo

Comment: You can't write any files on client side because react app works in browser. And Javascript in browser is not allowed to write files.

Comment: @Ken Bekov Actually what I want to do is that sometimetime client sees some error on react application but as a developer I cant show client that technical error instead of that I will show client a Fallback ui and that error should be logged in a centralized log file .That is what I want .Now do you understand what I am saying??

Comment: You cannot write to any file using React JS. Best case is utilizing local storage but then there is no way of obtaining that data unless you write code that implicitly uploads the errors to your server.

Answer (score 3):

As others have commented on, `React` runs in the browser and on the client side, so writing files is not possible.

However, I was searching myself for centralised logging for a frontend application and came across this post. Perhaps the question is not asked correctly, but basically I wanted to log and report crashes in the frontend to a central place or dashboard. When the app users run into issues, I at least know by seeing these errors in the dashboard. I found a few websites / services that can do this for you.

First tear is a free subscription

- [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/platforms/react-error-tracking/)
- [Sentry](https://sentry.io)
- [LogRocket](https://logrocket.com)
- [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com)
- [ClickUp](https://clickup.com)

First tear is paid

- [Instabug](https://instabug.com)
- [Raygun](https://raygun.com)
- [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com)

I've used this list myself to do some research and thought to share it here for anyone else who might currently be in my position. Perhaps it will help you along and you find it useful. Examples of how to implement them are in the docs. See which solution works best for you.